# SQL query with UNION, SELECT and JOIN

Tags: mysql, select, join, union-all

I have three tables with these fields:

`product_views`: `ProductMasterID, Date`

`product_clicks`: `ProductMasterID, Date`

`product_master`: `ProductMasterID, Category`

Anytime someone views a product on my site, it adds a row to `product_views`.
Anytime someone clicks on a product on my site, it adds a row to `product_clicks`

I am trying to write a SQL query (in MySQL/PHP) that will show me the popularity of products. Popularity is how many times it was viewed and clicked added together. I want to be able to also choose a date range, and within a certain category.

I can make it work without the date/category constrictions. I am now trying to add in the date range. This is what I have so far, for popularity of the last week:

```
SELECT *, COUNT(*) AS Popularity FROM 

    (SELECT product_views.ProductMasterID, product_views.Date 
         FROM product_views 
         WHERE product_views.Date BETWEEN '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now'))."' 
            AND '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7days'))."'"."

UNION ALL 

    SELECT product_clicks.ProductMasterID,product_clicks.Date 
        FROM product_clicks 
        WHERE product_clicks.Date BETWEEN '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now'))."' 
           AND '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7days'))."'".") a 

GROUP BY ProductMasterID ORDER BY Popularity DESC LIMIT 100"
```

Except that it doesnt work, it produces no results. However, if I delete either one of the `WHERE` clauses, then it does work for some reason, but I need both of them. So my questions are:

1. How to make it work with both `WHERE` clauses
2. How to do the category part e.g. selecting only products which have a category of 'Food'. I think I would have to do a join somewhere with the `product_master` table, but looks tricky.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming a typo, but when someone clicks a product should it not add a row to `product_clicks` instead of `product_views`?

Comment: @user1986985 why do you want to have a union here? Since your date range is the same, you can join two tables?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, I thought I had signed up to the email alert, and would receive an email when someone replied to this, but didnt get anything! Kevin, yes a type, have corrected it. bonCodigo, I'm having a look at your code now, so will see if I can it to work, then get back to you. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to use a **JOIN**, here is a solution:

- [SQLFIDDLE DEMO](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1156b/1)

Query:

```
SELECT M.PMID, M.CATEGORY, 
(COALESCE(V.VCNT,0) +
COALESCE(C.CCNT,0)) AS TOTAL_COUNT
FROM Master M
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PMID, COUNT(*) AS VCNT
           FROM VIEWS
           WHERE DATE between 
           DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
           and now()
           GROUP BY PMID) V
ON V.PMID = M.PMID
LEFT JOIN (SELECT PMID, COUNT(*) AS CCNT
           FROM CLICKS
           WHERE DATE between 
           DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL - 7 DAY)
           and now()
           GROUP BY PMID) C
ON C.PMID = M.PMID
GROUP BY M.PMID
;
```

Results:

```
| PMID | CATEGORY | TOTAL_COUNT |
---------------------------------
|    1 |    Shoes |           6 |
|    2 |    Books |           4 |
|    3 |     Food |           3 |
```

---

Using the UNION and just for the SQL part:

```
SELECT ID, COUNT(*) AS Popularity FROM 
(
    (SELECT product_views.ProductMasterID AS ID, count(*) 
         FROM product_views 
         WHERE product_views.Date BETWEEN '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now'))."' 
            AND '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7days'))."'"."
         GROUP BY product_views.ProductMasterID)

UNION ALL 

    (SELECT product_clicks.ProductMasterID AS ID, COUNT(*)
        FROM product_clicks 
        WHERE product_clicks.Date BETWEEN '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('now'))."' 
           AND '".date('Y-m-d',strtotime('-7days'))."'".") a
     GROUP BY product_clicks.ProductMasterID)

GROUP BY ProductMasterID 
ORDER BY Popularity DESC LIMIT 100"
```

<strike>How about this?</strike>

```
SELECT M.PMID, M.CATEGORY, COUNT(V.PMID), COUNT(C.PMID)
FROM MASTER M
LEFT JOIN VIEWS V
ON V.PMID = M.PMID
LEFT JOIN CLICKS C
ON C.PMID = M.PMID
WHERE V.DATE BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() INTERVAL - 7 DAY
AND C.DATE BETWEEN NOW() AND NOW() INTERVAL 7 DAY
GROUP BY M.PMID, V.DATE, C.DATE
;
```

Comment: Thanks very much bonCodigo, your JOIN solution worked a treat! That SQLFIDDLE site is useful, will be using it from now on for any particularly tricky queries.

Comment: @user1986985 happy to hear that and glad you got it worked :) Let us know if you have futher questions. [Please mark the answer if everything is alright with your question](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work). You can click on the tick near upvote buttons. So community knows your question is solved.